# How do I put a line break in to this code?

Tags: php, html

I have used this code when writing an email from within a CRM system. It displays the written text overlayed on the image selected.

```
<center>
  <img src="http://isposts.eybdashboards.com/txt2img/tip3.php?text=Hi ~Contact.FirstName~, hope you are well.
This is just a quick test.&xpos=210&ypos=160&fontsize=40&textrotate=3.0&imagefile=http://isposts.eybdashboards.com/txt2img/blankcard1.png & wwwidth=21" height="300" width="300" alt="Image to overlay words on" /> 
</center>
```

I have tried the standard html line breaks and others, but it doesn't give me a line break.

There has to be a way of doing this, but from what I have found from searching, just hasn't worked.

This link to an image is what I get at the moment (can't display an image in my post as I am new)

https://app.box.com/s/bcrdd2kzb3nlw2sr9njxb0bnopw7eokb

Comment: What you expect and what it is already there ?

Comment: Have you tried with \n ?
What have you tried 'till now ?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to use an escaped newline like this :

using Unix style line endings :

```
hope you are well.\nThis is just a quick test.
```

or MS-style line endings :

```
hope you are well.\r\nThis is just a quick test.
```

Comment: though i can't guarantee it will work in this case, since i have no idea of the code generating the picture. it might as well ignore newlines completely.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem to work. it just escapes them with an extra backslash like this : `..are well.\\nThis is just a quick test`

Comment: I have tried \n and it displays in the email as \\n then I tried \r\n and it displays as \\r\\n also just tried \\n but it displays within the email result as \\\\n

Comment: The output you're seeing is dependent on how the code on that server works. we have no idea how it works, or if it is even possible to add newlines :(